# Out of memory php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, apache, memory, pdo

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1310720) (tried to allocate 11109600 bytes) in

Reading though [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015569/fatal-error-out-of-memory-but-i-do-have-plenty-of-memory-php)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135587/php-fatal-error-out-of-memory) .

I got this below from `greg's` answer

> Of course this may reduce server performances as it takes ressources to kill and spaws new processes but at least it keeps the site working. You might be tempted to raise the number of running processes to keep performances high, be sure PHP (or apache) memory limit x max number of processes do not get over your server's physical ram.

and this below from `ray's` answer

> memory_limit: 20000M

Currently I am using xampp as server in my local pc so I am assuming that i can cancel out the first answer because currently my ram is not that high as that of a server I am thinking that if I put this in server I might not get the error. I am considering to the second solution to change the memory_limit. Even if i change my `memory_limit to 20000M` I still get the problem. But after restating `apache in xampp control panel` its ok again but if try doing what i was doing before the error return.

What other solutions are best to solve `Fatal error: Out of memory`.

Comment: Raise the memory even higher then.  If you don't have enough memory, you'll have to make your code more efficient or get more memory.

Comment: Is there a max value for memory_limit i didnt change it to higher because i am not sure if there is a maximum number for it @Jamen

Comment: I'm guessing that depends on how much memory your machine has.

Comment: `processor = i5 2.60ghz
ram = 8.00gb
system type = 64-bit OS,64x-based processor`
with this how much will be maximum

Comment: Right now `20000M` = `2.5gb` of RAM.  You have 8 total...  You could go up to like 4gb or higher, just don't do all 8, leave a bit of slack.

Comment: you will try to reserve 20gb of memory on a 8gb system?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo any suggestion on how to fix the current problem?

Answer (score 0):

I access the links and read your php code.

I suggest to change the isolate functions to only one, with this structure:

```
Select the data
    insert into table destination
    generate the line of file
```

If your file is only to be read on the next function, you don't need to generate anymore.